# Location-aware applications on WP7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps, cell

I would like to create a location-aware application on WP7.5

Is it possible to automatically get a trigger on location change without our application running on background?

For example:

I would like to know if a user has moved in a new location. If the user has moved I would like to trigger a specific event from my application. My only concern is that if I do that from my application I will consume a significant amount of battery. Is it a specific WP7 service which can inform my application that the user has changed his location and trigger an event from my application?

If it is possible can you please point me an example?

Comment: I think you should consider Periodic Agent implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Yes but I want to use it on a location aware application. Every 30 minutes a user can travell 50-60 khm..

Comment: So your application must be running to get more precise data. When it is you can use GeoCoordinateWatcher class to get callback when the position changed (you can set a threshold as well)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what if the user has click the Back button?

Comment: If that back button makes your app suspended your watcher will stop working.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 2 thinks:

- Use [Periodic Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to get geoposition every 30 minuts
- Use [`GeoCoordinateWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx) inside your app and set [`MovementThreshold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold.aspx) to get data only when position really changed. This way will work only if your app is actually running on the device - when user left the application watcher will stop working.