# How to update the userlocation to server when the location was changed in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to update the userlocation  to server when the location is changed  .Please tell me how to acheive this?

using below method:

```
void GeoPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            _pushpins.Clear();
            var cor = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
            //Using the current coordinates define the Map center to those coordinates.
            map.Center = cor;

            _pushpins.Add(new PushpinModel
            {
                UserId=userId,
                Description = "test",
                Name = "test",
                Location = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude,
                                                e.Position.Location.Longitude),
                DatetimeAdded = DateTime.Now
            });

            map.ZoomLevel = 15;

            //locationupdate method
            locationupdate(e.Position.Location.Latitude,
                                                e.Position.Location.Longitude);

        }

    private void locationupdate(double lat,double lon)
        {
              bool isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
                 if (isAvailable == true)
                 {
                     try
                     {

                         WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                         wc.DownloadStringAsync(
                         new Uri("http://{ipaddress}/Network/Records/UpdateLocation?userid="+userId+"&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lon));
                         wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                          new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
                                         wc_DownloadStringUpdateCompleted);
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         throw;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Network is not available.Please try again later");
                 }
       }
```

Please tell me the above will update the location whenever user was changed his location?

Comment: Do you realy expect someone to help you when you didn't try anything yourself first? Did you even try google?

Comment: i am searching like how to update the userlocation in windows phone 7 like that ...didn't get proper results....

Comment: please tell me i wrote the Geoposition Changed code in mainpage.xaml.when i am in another page and statred to moving to another location it will not update the userlocation...please help me out..

Comment: Sorry, i don't have time to try you're code now. But when you implemented this code in the Mainpage.xaml and go to another page this code will never execute. If you wan't that you should put this code in a seperate (static) class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location-aware applications on WP7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958045/location-aware-applications-on-wp7-5)

Comment: hi @BvdVen ...if i wrote the location changed in seperate static class where to call that staic class .to update the location continuosly.please let me any sample...

Comment: please tell me....after login i need to update the user location continuosly.if i wrote the location changed in a seperate class in that i need to send userid and lat,lon values to server continuously...

Comment: @WP7 I don't understand what part isnt working or what part you can't figure out?

Comment: can you briefly explain how to update the userlocation data continuously to server.as of now i wrote the geolocation changed code mainpage.xaml page while coming to this page location is updating but user is another page moving to another location then location was not updating..i need continuosly update userlocation when his location is changed..

Comment: did you read this:
Use GeoCoordinateWatcher (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx) inside your app and set MovementThreshold (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold.aspx) to get data only when position really changed. This way will work only if your app is actually running on the device - when user left the application watcher will stop working.

Comment: Thanks@BvdVen ....i given MovementThreshold value as 20 so that i didn't find the location is updating or not.it's clear i changed MovementThreshold as 0 ...now working

Comment: @WP7 Good to hear it helped you. (Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Separate your goal...

Do you already know how to get the user location?

Use background agents to run taks on the background (if necessary) http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.5-Use-Background-agents.aspx

Create a webservice to update you're server

Comment: we need to run background agents compulsory to update user location continuosly from app?in android locationlister automatically calling when user location is changed...please tell me

Comment: Found this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958045/location-aware-applications-on-wp7-5